# file upload using multipart in jsp

Tags: file-upload

how to upload files using multipart form in jsp. i have tried uploading and the file is getting uploaded but the other fields in the form like text/dropdown box,their value cannot be read

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Here's a much better answer along with *why* what you're trying doesn't work: [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

---

You must use a library such as [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) or [com.oreilly.servlet](http://www.servlets.com/cos/) if you're working with a container such as Tomcat 6 (or anywhere where the Servlet 3.0 spec isn't supported).

Comment: there is one more condition on the upload button...its dependent on the value of an input field in the same form.......if there is a value greater than two then only the file upload should be asked...i want to incorporate ajax in this...i will try the solution you provided and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the below code work fine because well tested.

JSP file:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <form method="POST" action="UploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                File:
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <br/>
                Destination:
                <input type="text" name="foldername"/>
                </br>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
            </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Servlet file:

```
    package com.servicehandler;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
    import javax.servlet.http.Part;



    /**
     * Servlet implementation class UploadServlet
     */
    @WebServlet("/UploadServlet")
    @MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*2,//2mb
                     maxFileSize=1024*1024*10,//10mb
                     maxRequestSize=1024*1024*50)//50mb
    public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public UploadServlet() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {

            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            String subfoldername=request.getParameter("foldername");
            String realpath=getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

            uploadFileTolocaldirectory(subfoldername,request);

            uploadFileToserverContextRealpath(subfoldername,realpath,request);

            uploadFileToapplicationdirectory(subfoldername,request);
        }




        public static void uploadFileTolocaldirectory(String foldername,HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalStateException, IOException, ServletException
        {

          String savePath="C:\\rootdir\\"+File.separator+foldername;
          File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
          if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) 
          {
              fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
          }

          Part part =request.getPart("file");
          String fileName = extractFileName(part);
          part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
        }

        public static void uploadFileToserverContextRealpath(String foldername,String realpath,HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalStateException, IOException, ServletException
        {
          String savepath=realpath+File.separator+foldername;
          File fileSaveDir = new File(savepath);
          if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) 
          {
              fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
          }

          Part part =request.getPart("file");
          String fileName = extractFileName(part);
          part.write(savepath + File.separator + fileName);
        }

        public void uploadFileToapplicationdirectory(String foldername,HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalStateException, IOException, ServletException
        {

            String path="D:\\yeldiallproject\\Fileuploadusingservlet\\WebContent";
            String savepath=path+File.separator+foldername;
            File fileSaveDir = new File(savepath);
          if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) 
          {
              fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
          }

          Part part =request.getPart("file");
          String fileName = extractFileName(part);
          part.write(savepath + File.separator + fileName);
        }


        private static String extractFileName(Part part) {
            String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
            for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
                if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                    String filename = content.substring(content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
                    return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1); // MSIE fix.
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        }
```